# FileSystemWatcher OnChanged event needs to rejoin UI thread

Tags: c#, events, user-interface, filesystemwatcher

How can I get the OnChanged event in a FileSystemWatcher to invoke a method on the UI thread once the OnChanged event is completed?

Or, just for the sake of knowledge, how can I get the OnChanged event to run entirely on the UI thread?

Comment: why don't you use a the dispatcher?

Answer (score 3):

If you want `FileSystemWatcher` to raise events on the UI thread and you are using Windows Forms, set the `SynchronizingObject` to a Control or Form. This isn't as useful if you are using WPF, where there isn't anything that implements `ISyncronizeInvoke`. You typically just call Invoke on the Dispatcher via `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke`, for example.

Comment: Note that if using Winforms, if you use the Designer to add the `FileSystemWatcher` object to the `Form` or `UserControl`, the Designer will automatically add the code needed to correctly initialize the `SynchronizingObject` property.